# Why does Draco's wand connect with Voldemort's in the movie?

Tags: harry-potter

In the movie, not the book, during the Battle of Hogwarts, Harry and Voldemort's wands connected when Expelliarmus and Avada Kedavra were cast in order to kill one another.
It was stated in Goblet of Fire (both book and movie) that only wands with similar cores do this.
Harry was using Draco Malfoy's wand, which has a core of Unicorn hair, and Voldemort was using the Elder Wand, which has a core of Thestral Hair.

Did they simply do this for a more dramatic effect, or did I miss something?

---

I would also like to address the fact that during the Battle of Hogwarts, in the movie, Voldemort and Death Eaters were Apparating and Disapparating within Hogwarts.
Isn't it true, that no matter what the circumstances are, you cannot Apparate within Hogwarts (unless you're Dumbledore)?

Comment: It would seem the inclusion of the wands connecting in the movie is for dramatic effect, for the reason you state. Wands can only connect if they share a dual core. In the books, even Dumbledore cannot Apparate inside Hogwarts; I believe only house-elves can. Hermione verifies this multiple times by quoting *Hogwarts, a History* to Ron and Harry. So, no, there is no Apparition inside Hogwarts in the books. The movies took a lot of creative license, but, then again, they had a lot of material to condense into just eight films. :)

Comment: @aSlytherin "There are advantages to being headmaster" or somesuch, in book 6.  But yeah, that was it as far as I recall

Comment: Technically speaking no apparation within Hogwarts is one of the protective spells. It's quite possible it was broken by DEs, though there's of course no evidence of that happening.

Comment: @Izkata - Where in book six? I know DD says something like, "Well, being me has its privileges" when Harry questions Apparition in the sixth movie. I'm not saying it's not in the book, but I just don't know where. :)

Comment: @aSlytherin I could be (once again) mixing the two up.  I would guess it was around when they were making the plans.

Comment: @Izkata - Well, I was intrigued, so I searched through *HBP* and found some info. In the chapter *Horace Slughorn*, Dumbledore confirms to Harry that no one can Apparate inside of or from Hogwarts. In the chapter *The Seer Overheard* DD and Harry go to Hogsmeade, where they are able to Apparate from the Hog's Head to the rock at the sea cave. So I *think* that the whole "Being me has its privileges" thing is probably just the movie. My best guess anyhow. :)

Comment: Jasmine Welcome to Stack Exchange, could you make an effort to split your current question into two. They are both very good points, I'd hate to see them suffer because of this.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for all of your input!  It really helps!  I'll try to split into two questions next time.  I didn't know it would be a big issue.  XD  :)

Comment: You are assuming Harry wanted to 'kill' using Expelliarmus. Harry would have known that all he had to do was disarm Voldemort since he was the true master of the Elder Wand.

Answer (score 15):

Voldemort could not use the Elder Wand effectively because he was not the master of the Elder Wand - Harry was. The movie takes liberties for dramatic effect - the wands do not connect in the book, Voldemort cannot use the Elder Wand against Harry, so when he tries to Avada Kedavra Harry, Harry simply disarms him and takes possession of the Elder Wand.

The movie also takes liberties with the Apparition inside Hogwarts. In the book there's no need for them to Apparate, they already have access to Hogwarts through Snape and the Death Eaters already within its walls.

Comment: I think this is basically a good answer. I just want to point out that Snape abandoned his post as headmaster before the Battle of Hogwarts ensued. Would the remaining Death Eaters have had the ability to lift the anti-Apparition enchantments protecting Hogwarts? I don't recall whether we actually see any DEs, or other members of Voldemort's ranks, Apparate into Hogwarts in *Deathly Hallows*. :) **ETA:** Sorry, I didn't read your answer right the first time. I see where you address the DE/Apparition issue.

Comment: Also, some of the DEs knew how to fly, so that could have been what you are thinking about.

Answer (score 3):

The excerpt from the 7th book **"Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows"** during the last minute battle shows that the 2 spells did hit each other. But then the elder wand's spell wasn't strong enough against its true master and so the spell rebounded back to Voldemort.This was not a connection of wands and no golden light encircled them both as happened in **"Goblet of Fire"**

> The light hit both of their faces
> at the same time, so that Voldemort’s was suddenly a flaming blur. Harry heard the high voice
> shriek as he too yelled his best hope to the heavens, pointing Draco’s wand:
> “Avada Kedavra!”
> “Expelliarmus!”
> The bang was like a cannon blast, and the golden flames that erupted between them, at the dead
> center of the circle they had been treading, marked the point where the spells collided. Harry saw
> Voldemort’s green jet meet his own spell, saw the Elder Wand fly high, dark against the sunrise,
> spinning across the enchanted ceiling like the head of Nagini, spinning through the air toward the
> master it would not kill, who had come to take full possession of it at last. And Harry, with the
> unerring skill of the Seeker, caught the wand in his free hand as Voldemort fell backward, arms
> splayed, the slit pupils of the scarlet eyes rolling upward. Tom Riddle hit the floor with a mundane
> finality, his body feeble and shrunken, the white hands empty, the snakelike face vacant and
> unknowing. Voldemort was dead, killed by his own rebounding curse, and Harry stood with two
> wands in his hand, staring down at his enemy’s shell.

Also In the book there's no need for them to Apparate, they already have access to Hogwarts through Snape and the Death Eaters are already within its walls and the people inside are manning the gates, which would not be required if apparation was possible

Comment: Just pointing out that the OP is asking why there *is* a discrepancy, not *if* there is a discrepancy, and I don't see that the OP mentioned anything about the golden cage which appeared upon Priori Incantatem in *Goblet of Fire*, but not in *Deathly Hallows*. Also, the OP is asking *if* Apparition is allowed at Hogwarts, not whether or not there was a need for the Death Eaters to Apparate. So, the answer to that is no. Apparition is not possible at Hogwarts. The exception is the house-elves, who *can* Apparate within and in and out of Hogwarts. :)

Comment: well he was talking about the connection of wands so i was just saying that if connected something like the priori might have reoccurred. :)

Answer (score 1):

One would presume that as most of the castles defenses had been destroyed, the spells/enchantments to prevent apparition would have been removed. Additionally as Snape was headmaster he could have done this. 
To answer your wand question, the connection may have occurred because of the connection between Harry and Voldemort "one cannot live while the other survives", so one would assume a connection so great between two immensely powerful wizards would give of a bit of spark- it could have also been caused by the fact that at the time Harry was the rightful owner of the elder wand, so as the rightful owner was fighting the wand with another this may fo caused the spark (and it looks pretty cool)

Answer (score 1):

You can never apperate out of Hogwarts, at any point, in book 6 Dumbledore does not apperate out of Hogwarts, him and harry walk to hogsmeade, and then apperate to the horcrux cave!

Comment: Generally what you've said is correct. However, Harry attends Apparition lessons in the Great Hall in his sixth year; the instructor mentions that Dumbledore has raised whatever enchantment normally prevents it from that section of the castle for the hour long period. So under normal circumstances it's not possible for a wizard to apparate or disapparate inside the Hogwarts grounds, but it's also possible for the Headmaster to remove that restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my late feedback, I can't really find a good quote for it, but if you have read book 6 you might know this fragment: Harry and Dumbledore both fly to the tower, with the Dark Mark in the sky. When they arrive there, and Dumbledore commands Harry to leave and put his cloak on, someone gets on the stairs. Dumbledore paralyzes Harry before Dumbledore loses his wand because of the Expelliarmus spell.

After Dumbledore died Harry noticed that he could move again, which gives me a reason to think that all the spells that have been made with the wand (in this case Stupefy/Petrificus Totalus) will be cancelled (Harry could move again, and nobody cast a counterspell on Harry so that he would be able to do so).

Answer (score -1):

About the apperate queston, maybe the apperate preventing spell have been dismissed when Dumbledore died? Isn't it mentioned in the book that when the owner of the Elder Wand fails to keep possesion of it, all the spells that have been made with it will be dissmissed? So that means, if Dumbledore had created the spells, they have been dismissed, and Voldemort made a great use of that.

My apologies for my english, my grammar is not that great :)

Comment: Can you back this up with a quote from the books?